# Javascript single page app 1 instance of a class accessible by all pages

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, singlepage

I have a question about javascript single page app.
Suppose I have a class that requires retrieval and storage of values in that class from different pages.

Example:
After clicking a button on page A, data is stored in that class. We will now continue to page B, where we store additional data in the same class, without losing the data stored by page A.

I'm using Javascript, with knockout and PHP / MySQL as backend.

Is this possible? If so what are the possibilities, frameworks? Or am I asking the impossible here?

Thank you,

Regards,

Erik

Comment: If it's a single page then there shouldn't be reloads between view A and B so the object instance isn't destroyed and the data is still there. If there is a reload between A and B then I wouldn't consider it a single page application. You can use `localStorage` to persist data between page reloads.

Comment: I ended up using amplify.store().
Another welcome feature of amplify is that it has publish and subscribe for notifying other viewmodels.